# apply group_by() function after select() function

Tags: r, select, encoding, group-by, dplyr

I want to use  group_by() function after select() function.
But Under the program show error message. How I can do?

CODE:

```
library(tidyverse)
dt <- data.frame("トヨタ" = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 "ホンダ" = c(4,3,2,1), 
                 "グループ" = c(1,2,1,2))

dt %>%
   select(`トヨタ`, `グループ`) %>%
   group_by(`トヨタ`)
```

RESULT:

`Error: unknown column 'トヨタ'`

encoding is `UTF-8`

CODE:

```
dt %>%
  select(`トヨタ`,`グループ`) %>%
  names(.) %>% Encoding
```

RESULT:

`[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8"`

Comment: You code is working with my Mac; no error message appears.

Comment: OS is windows(appear error message).
This probrem is depend on OS?

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue related to OS.

Comment: Code works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with R 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

the first data.frame column names encoding is "unkown".
but after `select()`, column  names encoding changed "UTF-8".

First data encoding:

```
> names(dt) %>% Encoding
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

a temporary measure:

```
dt %>%
  select(`トヨタ`, `グループ`) %>%
  `colnames<-`(enc2native(colnames(.))) %>%
  group_by(`トヨタ`)
```

Thanks:http://notchained.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/04/29/222453